# The average distance from the centre of a square or rectangle to a point within this shape

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I know that for a circle, the average distance from the center to a point is $(2/3)\sqrt{A/pi}$ in which A is the surface of the circle. This is understandable for me. However, I am wondering about a formula to calculate the average distance from the center of a square and rectangle to a random point.

I have found similar questions on this forum, but I have not yet found an answer that I could grasp my mind around. I can imagine that for the rectangle, it would incorporate like a length vs. width ratio or something.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: For a point $P$ inside a square/rectangle/any convex $n$-gon, cut the $n$-gon into $n$ triangles with $P$ as apex and edges of original $n$-gon as bases.The average distance you seek is an area weighted average of average distance of $P$ to these triangles. These set of average distances is simply $\frac23$ of average distance of $P$ to corresponding base. When $P$ is within $n$-gon, the problem reduces to finding   average distances of $P$ to individual edges of original $n$-gon. Just setup the integral and compute, it isn't that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on random points distribution.
Let this distribution is uniform by area.
Let center of rectangle is $O(0;0)$, sides are parallel to axes and one of vertices is $A(a;b)$ with $a>0$, $b>0$. Then all rectangle points are given by inequalities $$-a<x<a \land -b<y<b$$ Let $(x;y)$ is random point, then distance from this point to center is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then average distance is $$\frac{1}{4ab}\int_{-a}^a \int_{-b}^b \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx=\\
\frac{1}{6ab} \left(a^3 \ln \left(\frac{b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a}\right) +2 ab
   \sqrt{a^2+b^2} +b^3 \ln
   \left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{b}\right)\right)$$